# What is a term for someone who has a rather frown face?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology, pejorative-language

With tensed muscles and looking "difficult" (as I don't know how to describe this any better...) Not done most excessively (a face frown as much as possible), but kind of like someone who (pretended or not) is having a hard time. You may have seen this kind of face before from young people who take a lot of "selfies".

Comment: Where I live, that may be called the *bitch face*, which also implies some genuine hostility.

Comment: There must be a "nicer" way of saying that?!

Comment: I've also heard it called *a chronically frowny face,* if the person does it often enough.  To be honest, I think that *frowny face* is probably sufficient.

Comment: @Anonym That's what I just mentioned in my answer comment too! ''Frowny face'' is just fine.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 3):

I would say the person has a **dour** expression or is stern or is gloomy.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Fleer](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/182065/fleer)**
>         To make a wry face in contempt, or to grin in scorn; to deride; to sneer; to mock; to gibe.

.

> **[Gurning](http://thorne_slang.enacademic.com/3020/gurning)**: intoxicated by drugs or drink. The term was popular among adolescents and students from the later 1990s and refers particularly
>   to someone feeling the ill effects of drugs. It is inspired by the
>   verb to 'gurn' (from Middle English girn, a form of 'grin'), which
>   means to pull grotesque faces.

.

> **[Pretty Girls, Ugly Faces](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pretty-girls-ugly-faces)**:Pretty Girls, Ugly Faces is a photo fad in which girls take pictures
>   of themselves while posing in an unflattering manner, making a silly
>   face or performing a physically strenuous activity. Origin
>
> The single topic Tumblr blog Pretty Girls Making Ugly Faces[1](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/182065/fleer)
>   launched on September 26th, 2011, featuring nine photos of different
>   females making unattractive-looking faces by manipulating their mouths
>   and necks. Throughout 2011, the blog was regularly updated with the
>   bloggers’ own photos as well as user-submitted images before going on
>   a hiatus in June 2012.

.

> **[Duckface](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/duck-face)**: also known as “Myspace Face”, is a pejorative term for a facial
>   expression made by pressing one’s lips together into the shape of a
>   duck’s bill. It is often associated with selfies of teenage girls
>   posted on social networking sites like Myspace and Facebook.

&

> **[Girning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/girning)**:  1.     to snarl 2. to grimace; pull grotesque faces

Comment: I know this term, but didn't mean pressing the lips together.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **[hatchet-faced](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/hatchet-faced?topic=not-attractive-to-look-at)**. It is used as the opposite of smiling,

> I thus became both **hatchet-faced** inspector and **smiling**, helpful adviser who encouraged rather than drove.

-Admiral Sandy Woodward, *One Hundred Days* (2003)

**Other examples**

- Hank Patterson was an actor in television programs *Gunsmoke* and *Green Acres*. He had a hatchet-faced expression in some, but not all roles.
- Jodi Arias was described as having a hatchet-faced expression in court.

Comment: Isn't hatched-faced more biological? The face I mean could be attempted by anyone. More like an intended facial expression.

Comment: @user76935 No, Jodie Arias had a hatchet-faced expression in court, but not in other contexts. I will revise my answer to clarify. I know what you meant, by "frowny face" ;o) I think that is a very nice term, just as is!

Comment: I personally think ***hatchet-faced*** actually *is* the best word for what OP seeks to describe. But all these (effectively, irrelevant) pictures mean this isn't the best *answer*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to show that it was a mutable facial expression, not biological, in response to OP's comment. I will happily remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a 'Melancholic person'.
A person having a hard time has a 'melancholic face'

Comment: Why would a young person show his melancholic face? While, in fact, they are young, and most of those I saw, have an abundence of friends and buzzing lifestyles to make them happy/cheerful/enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **to have a grim expression on one's face** may come close to what are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that person either has a **scowl** (jaws clinched more, little more frown in it) or a **glare**.  Often models are told to do one or the other to tighten their face muscles.

> A fierce or angry stare.

Answer (score -2):

I've heard this kind of stern, impassive look described as a *prison face.*

Comment: Though, ironically, it doesn't look like the face of a prisoner? Which is, perhaps, more lacking of any (emotional) expression.